# How to access child objects from parent object in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, three.js

I've used mesh to add objects and thereafter I added mesh to the scene. Now I want to access the objects from mesh so that I could perform rotating the objects and its children in corresponding their meshes.

Sample code, but advise to look for jsfiddle link for detail knowledge: http://jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/PrVbg/3/

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.Geometry());
scene.add(mesh);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setClearColorHex(0xffffff, 1);
renderer.setSize( width, height );


for ( var i = 0; i <nSize; i++)
{
    var k = i%10,
        j = (i-k)/10;

    j = j*2 - 10;
    k = k*2 - 10;

    cone1 = lc_relationship.sensor1[i].Geometry; 
    mesh.add(cone1);
    cone2 = lc_relationship.sensor2[i].Geometry;
    mesh.add(cone2);
    cone3 = lc_relationship.sensor3[i].Geometry;
    mesh.add(cone3);
    cone1.position.set(j, k, lc_relationship.sensor1[i].z_cordinate);
    cone2.position.set(j, k, lc_relationship.sensor2[i].z_cordinate);
    cone3.position.set(j, k, lc_relationship.sensor3[i].z_cordinate);
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to get someone to write your code for you. This is not going to happen. Create an example with one parent cone and one child cone. Learn how to use three.js to manipulate those two cones, individually or together. Once you know how to do that, then work your way up to a more complicated structure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But FYI, I was expecting only a suggestion but someone comes up with full code its upto their interest. Please don't be so judgmental. Btw, my datastructure is a custom object.

Comment: I also missed my work in jsfiddle link to put in my question: http://jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/PrVbg/3/

Comment: My apologies. I did not intend to be judgmental... But take my advice anyway. ;-)